# Reading from text file to ListBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file, listbox, streamreader

I am having a bit of trouble reading data from a text file. This almost works, however data in separate lines in the text file is combined to one long line in the ListBox. How else to do it?

```
Private Sub frmOpretrskAar_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "c:\users\claus\onedrive\SLERP\fmr.txt"
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
    LBmuligeFirmaer.Items.Add(objReader.ReadToEnd)
    objReader.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: try `FileReadAllLines`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [ListBox.Items.AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx) method to add an array, in this case it would be an array that represents the lines of the text file. You can get the lines by using [IO.File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Here is a quick example:

```
LBmuligeFirmaer.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\users\claus\onedrive\SLERP\fmr.txt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple -

```
List<string> _list = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
```

See the below image -

[image]

Comment: No need to convert the array to collection to a List(Of String) since the ListBox's AddRange method accepts an array.

Comment: You are absolutely right when someone is directly working on Windows Forms.

Comment: List<String> does not support in older version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.
Try this code:

```
   Dim FILE_NAME As String = "c:\users\claus\onedrive\SLERP\fmr.txt"
   Dim AllLines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)
   For i As Integer = 0 To AllLines.Count - 1
       LBmuligeFirmaer.Items.Add(AllLines(i))
   Next
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't test this in my IDE currently so tell me if something doesn't work right but I have used something similar:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms

'assigning a string value to the file's location
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "c:\users\claus\onedrive\SLERP\fmr.txt"

'clearing the listbox
LBmuligeFirmaer.items.clear

'declaring a filereader
Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
fileReader =       
'obtaining file location from string to the stringreader    
My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(FILE_NAME)
Dim stringReader As String
'reading first line
stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
'adding line to the listbox
LBmuligeFirmaer.items.add(stringreader)
'reading second line
stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
'adding line to listbox
LBmuligeFirmaer.items.add(stringreader)

'and so on...
```